# What wrong with my Push function ? Stacking

Tags: java

Doing this for my project, using jFrame.

[image]

My problem is, when I input **first:1** , **Second: 2** , **third: 3**

and I clicked view stack, and the problem shows `[ 1 , 2 , 3 , 0 , 0 , 0 . . . ]`
I think the view should be `[ 3 , 2 , 1 , 0 , 0 . . . .]`
what what I understood about push.

code used :

// Global Variable

```
int[] myStack = new int [10];
int top = -1;
```

// Push Button

```
 if ( top == 9){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Stack Full!");
    }else{
        int val = Integer.parseInt(pushtxt.getText());
        top++;
        myStack[top] = val;
        pushtxt.setText("");
    }
}
```

// View Stack Button

```
if (top == -1){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Stack Empty!");
}else{
    viewtxt.setText("");
    for (int x=0; x<=9; x++){
        viewtxt.setText(viewtxt.getText()+" "+ myStack[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us *all* of the *relevant* code, especially regarding the stack. @Jason, my apologies.

Comment: @hexafraction: No, please not the *entire* code. Just the *relevant* code. Be concise, precise and on point.

Comment: You have an expectation. Your expectation is not being met. You need to take a deep breath, open up a debugger (or use `System.out.println` statements or some other form of rudimentary tracing) and find the *first* line of code where your expectations are violated as you step through the program. Then you need to figure out *why* it's happening and if it's because you have a bug in your code or if it's because your expectation is wrong. Repeat until the bugs in your code or the bugs in your brain are gone.

Comment: sorry im not really good at posting ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stacks are FiLo, First in, last out. Generally stacks are used in a manner where you push items (the first being the bottom of the stack) and they keep on stacking. When you need to get values off of the stack you pop, going back in reverse order.

So the order you entered for data would store as:

1,2,3 
bottom -> top

Your data is correct, it is as it should be.

So next you'll want to write a pop function, where you grab the value at the top of the stack and then decrement the top variable.

Popping your stack one at a time would return in the following order:
3
2
1

From what you were describing, I think perhaps you were going to pop from the front of the stack? If that is what you want to do, you would have to shift all of your values every-time you pushed a new value. What you currently have now is better code than shifting all your values on every push =]

You are on the right track.

**EDIT** I have not used swing in a while, but hopefully this will lead you in the right direction (I looked at some old code to make sure my syntax was correct, have not tested though). To answer the question you asked in my comment, your code would look something similar to the following for the pop function and setting the text for the popTextField

your pop function should look something like the following:

```
/**
* The code for the button press could be as simple as follows
*/
popBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
        try{
            popTextField.setText(popStack);
        }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            popTextField.setText("The stack is empty");
        }
    }
});
```

the pop function can be really simple. You do not need to use exceptions - but it is good practice.

```
/**
* Simple Pop function
*/
private int popStack(){
    if(top >= 0){
        return myStack[top--];
    }else{
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The stack is empty");
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped! have fun =]

Comment: I added some code to my response above =] Note though, I didn't test it, I did however verify the syntax with some of my older code. It should either work or be very close (you'll have to change some variable names)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding the way a stack works.  More specifically, the algorithm you use to display the stack is incorrect.  In your case, you start at the bottom of the stack (where x=0) and work your way towards the top (actually, beyond the top, where x=9).  This is why your output seems reversed to you (it's also full of zeros that you shouldn't be printing).

When displaying the stack, you should start at the top (x=2) and work your way towards the bottom (x=0).  If you do things this way, then the output will be correct.

Comment: No.  I'm happy to explain things to you, but I'm not happy to do your work for you.